# CSS responsive background image as full-sized image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, background-image

I'm trying to layer two images on top of each other, and I've found the easiest way is to set one as the background image for the header tag, and then another inside the header tag itself.

However, the background image I want to set is the banner that needs to display in full, and as a background image, the size of the tag around it falls to fit only the size of the second image on top of it.

I want to keep the banner/background image responsive in size, so I can't just set a specific height and width.

How do I make the background image act as a banner? (while still having my second image layered on top?)

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <img src="topImage.jpg" />
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header{
    background-image: url('bannerImage.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

/*This image is smaller than the background banner image*/
header img{
    display: block;
    max-width: 20%;
    height: auto;
}
```

I'm seeking a CSS solution, but also open to JavaScript if it applies. No Jquery please.

edit:
Sorry, when I said div I simply meant the tags I applied the stylings to. Updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: post a fiddle please

Comment: Strange how you mention divs when there is no `<div>` to be seen in your code. Can you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an image in you page body and apply Z-index to it (banner image).

```
//Banner image
.imgOne
{
     position: absolute  !important;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     z-index: -1 !important;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
}

//Second overlaying image
.imgTwo
{
     position: relative;
     width:30% !important;
     float :left; //Optional; you could specify left and top for position
     height:30% !important;
}
```

If you are using float on second image you can see the outcome if you dont want other elements to float around second image you could use clear property for those elements like below.

```
p {
    border: 1px solid red;
    clear: left;
}
```

Fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/e1hysrce/

Lmk if it works for you or if you find something better share.